# PHP Excel generation fails when using Android

Tags: php, android, forms, apache, excel

I have an issue with PHP POST values submitted by Android Devices.
The issue does not happen on PC, nor on IPad or IPhone.

This is my code to fetch the values submitted via Form from my website.

```
$year =  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["year"]);
```

Here is a "snippet" of my `PHP` code for generating an Excel file which is sent to the browser for downloading. This code sets the Title of the Worksheet.

So this works perfectly:

```
$objSheet->setTitle("Report 2013");
```

But this does not work (when using android phone, it works in evertything else)

```
$objSheet->setTitle("Report " . " " . $year);
```

The variable `$year` somehow is `null` when i try to use it.

if i do a `var_dump($year)`, or `print_r($year)`,  or `echo $year`
the value `"string(4) 2013"` is there!! The `$_POST` variable is populated and the values are correct.
I checked for strange headers in `$_REQUEST` global and the only difference i found were these headers:

```
 [langedit] => "" [lang] => "" [cprelogin] => no
```

What could possibly make my PHP variables go wild and crazy  when processing a Android device HTTP request?

Comment: First step of debugging is to simply as much as possible - This almost certainly has nothing to do with your spreadsheet library, so I'd factor that out and make as simple a bit of code as possible that produces the bug you're seeing.  (my guess is you happen to be hitting a different code path).

Comment: Also, not sure why you're escaping year like that if it's not being included in an SQL insert.  `filter_var($_POST['year'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);` would make more sense here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php - there's nothing much safer than an integer :)

Comment: actually, i am using it in a SQL query. I escape it to prevent SQL injection. There are many other "POST values" that i am using to write data in the excel. But each variable behaves like the $year variable.  The Excel library gets "null" strings. It's making me crazy, i can't undestand why.

Comment: Fair enough.  But yeah, my point still stands.  simplify as much as possible, and `var_dump($year)` before / after every time `$year` is used and it should be pretty obvious where the fault is.

Comment: i've been debugging the variables around everywhere for 4 days (for real).  i can't understand  why calling  setTitle("Report 2013") is different  from calling   setTitle("Report ". $year).  When i am Truly convinced that the variable  is "2013" !

Comment: also, why does the error happen only on Android browser??? that is the part that bugs me.